# PHP Session Cookie Default Domain

Tags: php

Is the default domain for a php session cookie always the same as $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. Where can I find this information in the php manual? It seems to be $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], but I would like verification.

Comment: By default the domain is empty and that information is simply not sent to the client. Consult the HTTP specification and/or your browser documentation to find out what this means for you.

Answer (score 0):

the cookie is set by the browser and depends on the domain open on it. It is the same as $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but that doesn't mean that you can change the variable to change the domain of the session cookie.

Comment: I am seeing Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=28jodee15pbunp7nddgm466sa7; path=/ in the response headers, so I don't think it is set by the browser. I am just interested to know how it picks the domain.